# Drill down in graph using FusionCharts Free for axis

Tags: fusioncharts

I have the following input xml file:

```
    <Company >
    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:00.01</timeStamp>
        <Price>  25.02</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:00.02</timeStamp>
        <Price>  15</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.025</timeStamp>
        <Price>  15.02</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.031</timeStamp>
        <Price>  18.25</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.039</timeStamp>
        <Price>  18.54</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:01.050</timeStamp>
        <Price> 16.52</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:02.01</timeStamp>
        <Price>  17.50</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:03.01</timeStamp>
        <Price>  25.02</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:05.02</timeStamp>
        <Price>  30</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:11.025</timeStamp>
        <Price>  32.25</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:12.031</timeStamp>
        <Price>  26.05</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:15.039</timeStamp>
        <Price>  18.54</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:00:19.050</timeStamp>
        <Price> 16.52</Price>
    </shareprice>

    <shareprice>
        <timeStamp> 12:01:02.01</timeStamp>
        <Price>  17.50</Price>
    </shareprice>
</Company>
```

I carry out some analysis in R and produce two XML files. The first output file is in the format for a FusionChart Free Chart:

```
<graph caption="Share Data Wave" subcaption="For Person's Name" xAxisName="Time"  yAxisMinValue="-0.025" yAxisName="Voltage" decimalPrecision="5" formatNumberScale="0" numberPrefix="" showNames="1" showValues="0" showAlternateHGridColor="1" AlternateHGridColor="ff5904" divLineColor="ff5904" divLineAlpha="20" alternateHGridAlpha="5">
    <set name="2010-08-26 12:00:21.040" value="25.020000" hoverText = "The difference  from last value: 0" ></set>
    <set name="2010-08-26 12:01:02.531" value="15.000000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: -10.02" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:02:02.212" value="15.020000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 0.0199999999999996" ></set>
    <set name="2010-08-26 12:02:09.426" value="18.250000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 3.23" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:02:20.364" value="18.540000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 0.289999999999999" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:02:58.058" value="16.520000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: -2.02" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:03:10.262" value="17.500000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 0.98" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:03:13.085" value="25.020000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 7.52" ></set>
    <set name="2010-08-26 12:04:07.601" value="30.000000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 4.98" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:04:57.355" value="32.250000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 2.25" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:05:07.259" value="26.050000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: -6.2" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:05:15.503" value="18.540000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: -7.51" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:06:06.538" value="16.520000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: -2.02" ></set>
     <set name="2010-08-26 12:06:49.746" value="17.500000" hoverText = "The difference from last value: 0.98" ></set>
</graph>
```

My question is after seeing the full chart a user only wants to see data between times. In the above format it would be the name tag. How can I edit the xml file to show just the requested data points. Can this be done using a PHP form (or something similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is highly probable using PHP. If you wish to edit the XML as shown by you and retain some  elements as per selected time range, please follow th steps:

Steps can be :

1. Use form elements to select the time range.
2. As per the range select the data that falls into the range using PHP XML parser
3. Generate FusionCharts specific XML

or

1. Use form elements to select the time range.
2. Parse the created FusionCharts specific XML to remove all the values of name attributes of set nodes which do not fall in the range
3. Use this final XML to generate chart.

I can put here a small PHP example for you so that you can use that.